# Removing part of a string between indices

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, replace, indices

I gotta write a function that when given a string, finds the first appearance of the
substring 'not' and 'bad'. If the 'bad' follows the 'not',it replaces the whole 'not'...'bad' substring with 'good'. 
ex:'This dinner is not that bad!' yields: This dinner is good!
I tried:

```
def not_bad(s):
    sub1='not'
    sub2='bad'
    if s.find(sub1) < s.find(sub2):
        s = s[0:int(s.find(sub1))]
        s= s + 'good'
        return s
    else:
        return s
```

but it doesn't yield the exclamation mark at the end.

Comment: What about `s.replace('not that bad','good')?`

Comment: The function is supposed to work for any given string.
So if the given string is "The tea is not that hot" it won't work

Comment: `not that` is always present in the string? And how do you find the antonyms ? You need some library for it. Or store antonyms for words.

Comment: Why are you using Python 2? Also, the indentation of your code is broken.

Comment: It's part of an exercise, there's a separate code that checks mine by applying parameters.
Also if my indentation was broken the code wouldn't work at all, but it does.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` here.

```
import re
s='This dinner is not that bad!'
re.sub(r'not \w+ bad','good',s)
# 'This dinner is good!'
```

`\w+` - matches any word character (equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`)

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use regex because I don't really know how. but my solution:

```
def not_bad(s):
    sub1='not'
    sub2='bad'
    temp = None
    if s[len(s)-1] == "!": #-> this checks if there is "!"
        temp = s[len(s)-1]
    if s.find(sub1) or s.find(sub2):
        s = s[:int(s.find(sub1))]
        s += 'good'
        if temp:
            s += temp
        return s
    else:
        return s
```

Comment: you can write `'and'` instead of the `'or'`, both work for me.. but do your test :) hope.i helped

Comment: Is there a way to make the function replace the indices between not and bad regardless of the exclamation mark?

Comment: my code checks if there is exclamation mark just to know if to put it in the end or not. you can delete the `'if'` that checks if there is exclamation mark.

Comment: if you want only to change the word 'not' you can do this: `print(s[s.find(sub1):s.find(sub1)+len(sub1)])` this will catch the start index of the word 'not' and run from the start index to start index + the length of the word 'not'. if you print it, it will print 'not'. :) notice this is not the best way, a better way is to save the returned value of `s.find(sub1)` in a variable

Answer (score 0):

@ch3ster is correct, but that would account for just one word. For any more characters you should try this

```
import re

string1="the dinner is not nice 27 that bad"
print(re.sub(r"not[a-zA-Z _0-9]*bad","good",string1))
```

Outputs

```
the dinner is good
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check this.

```
def not_bad(main_str):
    sub1='not'
    sub2='bad'
    if main_str.find(sub1) < main_str.find(sub2):
        main_str = main_str[0:int(main_str.find(sub1))] + 'good' + main_str[int(main_str.find(sub2)) + len(sub2):]
        return main_str
    else:
        return main_str


output_str = not_bad('This dinner is not that bad!')
print(output_str)
```

Output:

```
This dinner is good!
```